# scp a mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, curl, ssh, scp, bitbucket

**I have a shared web host and I am trying to figure out a way to download the latest copy of a private project from bitbucket onto the server.**

The server does not have any versioning tools installed, but **it does have scp and ssh** with a jailshell level of access. It also has wget and curl...

Can I can do something like this?

```
scp ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/jespern/testrepo ~/public_html
```

I don't have a problem setting up the identity files / DSA keys, but I'm not exactly sure how the protocols are put together here so I need some help with the basic syntax.

Or, if scp is not the way to go, does ssh have an option for doing this? or is it possible to use CURL or wGet to grab the latest version of the repository and then reconstruct it on the server?

I am sure there is a way to do this, so please don't respond saying "it can't be done."

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download from bitbucket using either http with URL like this:

- http://bitbucket.org/jespern/rewsfeed/get/tip.tar.bz2

Notice how `tip` can be used in place of a revision ID in that URL form to always get the latest snapshot.

Alternately, you can just install Mercurial in your home directory on the shared web host -- people have succeeded in doing that on almost every webhost out there no matter how locked down they are.

Then you can just do: `/home/me/bin hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/jespern/testrepo ~/public_html`

Comment: excellent! the archived version of the tip works great! after more researching i see it is usually available in gz, bz2, and zip.

Comment: regarding the install - i have a folder called mercurial with pre-compiled files, like hg.pyc. do i put the mercurial folder inside ~/bin/ ? that would make the path to hg.pyc ~/bin/mercurial/hg.pyc. I know i need to chmod +x the hg.pyc file, what else do i need to do to keep from having to specify the full path to it every time?

Comment: that's a biggest question, but if you google 'mercurial' + 'dreamhost' you'll see all sorts of walk through documents for setting it up on restricted shared hosts.  The key is doing 'make local' on a different system and then moving the whole tree up there -- making sure to get the system architecture (32 vs. 64, etc.) right.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I matched up the 32/64 bit and got a local copy. Basically the pyc files are the ones that need to be made locally. Then I put the hg file inside the ~/bin/ folder and it has a line in there which points to where the mercurial folder with all the rest of the stuff is - just edited that. now it works very well! thanks for the help!